# How to reproduce Flash effect with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I'd like to reproduce [this flash effect](http://www.sopranowebdesign.com/animation/) with jQuery. Could you please point me to some good tutorials or give me some pointers?
Thanks!

Comment: This isn't really a question for stackoverflow. Once you've started though, and come across a specific problem you can't fix, then you've got a question.

Answer (score 5):

i use http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/